# execute cmd for /f %%i in ( ...) do set

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, windows-scripting

In a .bat file, the following line can not execute:

```
for /f %%i in ('call _confutil.bat get DATA_PATH') do set DATA_PATH=%%i
```

it returns the error as:

```
'call _confutil.bat get DATA_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

However, on another Windows machine, there is no problem to execute this line.
Any idea what the reason for the difference could be?

Comment: If it was just that `_confutil.bat` was missing, the error message would only be `'_confutil.bat' is not recognized [...]`. The fact that the word `call` is part of the error message suggests that either the single quotes are smart quotes instead of regular quotes or your script is saved with the wrong encoding.

Comment: (btw: you don't need `call` here, as the command is executed as another process anyway)

Comment: Are you executing as administrator? Because running a script as an administrator will be executed in system32

Comment: on my machine, for /f %%i in ('dir') do echo %%i, will return error : 'dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  The other machine  is ok. Both are system admin and identical PATH.

Comment: What does `set comspec` say on both computers?

Comment: both machine are : echo %COMSPEC%
   C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;

Comment: I hope the `;` is a typo in your comment and not really there. Besides that, I'm out of ideas. I was only able to reproduce your exact error message by messing with `%comspec%`.

Comment: @Stephan, the ; is not a typo it is in the COMSPEC. and it is the difference between these two machines. How don't know why ; is there. I am not allowed to use environment edit to modify. However, I set COMSPEC=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe locally, I still got the error.  Can you share me how to mess up %comspec% to reproduce this error?

Comment: see `set /?` and `setx /?`